# BlackBerry Docs to Go shows Excel very hidden worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, blackberry

I've come across something and I'm not sure if there is a solution to it.

I have built an Excel 2013 workbook that has a number of very hidden worksheets. The data in these sheets is sensitive and should not be available unless their log on ID is recorded in one of the very hidden sheets. This all runs with VBA and works well in normal everyday use.

However, this workbook was emailed and picked up on a BlackBerry which has Docs to Go installed. When the workbook is opened with this app, all the very hidden sheets and data is available. The VBA & workbook are both password protected.

Has anyone ever come across this before and know if it can be resolved?

Many thanks